# innerHTML not working properly Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to display " the link to " ( link ) " was added" when 'submit' btn is pressed. I am new to Javascript. 
I coded something like this but it is not working.

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var link = document.getElementById("link");
var url = document.getElementById("url");

var news = "The link to" + link + "was successfully added";
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = news;
```

Comment: Define "not working".  In what way is it failing?  Is there an error in the browser's debugging console?  Unexpected output?  When you step through the code in your browser's debugger, does each variable contain what you expect?  What is the result?

Comment: I would re-itterate what @David said.. And the `id` called `form` would be a red flag straight off the bat. Would be important to see your relevant HTML

Comment: It is returning this in the browser "The link to[object HTMLInputElement]was successfully added"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get `.value` of the input.
Check this.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
 var link = document.getElementById("link");
var url = document.getElementById("url");

var news = "The link to " + link.value + " was successfully added";
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = news;
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" id="url" />
        <br>
 <input type="text" id="link" />
        <br>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<h1 id="new">
</h1>
```

Comment: Glad your issue is resolved. Accept the answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment on the question above:

> It is returning this in the browser "The link to[object HTMLInputElement]was successfully added"

Sounds like `.innerHTML` is working just fine.  You're simply trying to output an entire HTML element instead of just the value it holds:

```
var link = document.getElementById("link").value;
```